# Trying to dodge geom_point and geom_errorbar coordinately

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble dodging my data points and error bars coordinately. I have created some reproducible data. I am still fairly new to R and could use any advice with this issue.

Thanks,
Kurt

```
O2 <- c("H","N", "N","N","H","H","N", "N","N","H")
Sp <- c("Dm","Dm","Dd","Dr","Dp","Dm","Dm","Dd","Dr","Dp")
Lenz <- c(2.2,1.4,1.0,1.9,2.2,2.3,1.1,1.0,0.9,0.3)
se <- c(0.16,0.12,0.03,0.07,0.25,0.15,0.1,0.05,0.03,0.04)
oxy.labsS <- c("Hyp", "Nor")

names(oxy.labsS) <- c("H", "N")
df <- data.frame(O2,Sp,Lenz,se)
limitsS <- aes(ymin = df$Lenz-df$se,ymax = df$Lenz+df$se)
pd <- position_dodge(width = 0.5)
kSAMP <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Sp, y = Lenz, group = O2))+
  geom_point(size = 4, position = pd)+
  geom_errorbar(limitsS,width =0.1, position = pd)+
  ylab("enz")+
  xlab("")+
  facet_grid(~O2,scales = "free", space = "free", switch = "both", labeller = labeller(O2 = oxy.labsS))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(strip.placement = "outside", 
    strip.background = element_blank(), 
    strip.text = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
    axis.text.x=element_text(size=15, face = "italic"),
    axis.text.y=element_text(size=20),
    axis.title=element_text(size=20,face="bold")
  )
```

Comment: So what exactly is the desired outcome here? How is this plot different than the one you want?

Comment: I would like the data points and error bars to be jittered horizontally. Perhaps I should be using a position_jitter rather than position_dodge? In my full data set I have more data points and the errorbars are overlapping each other.

Comment: Thanks for the reproducible example. I can't easily figure out how to do this without manually supplying a "dodged" x coordinate for the points and errorbars.

Comment: There's a position_jitterdodge for doing both